# Enabling flat rate shipping in Magento 1.7 without displaying it in the front-end

Tags: magento-1.7

I need to enable flat rate shipping in Magento, but do not want it to display on frontend anywhere.

Comment: if anyone have the solution for this please help me

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to create a custom moudle for this.

i have created a one for this for admin free shipping module.This is my model file.this may use for you.

```
<?php

class Namespace_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Customrate
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
    protected $_code = 'my_customrate';
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {

        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {

                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $freeBoxes += $item->getQty() * $child->getQty();
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeBoxes += $item->getQty();
                }
            }
        }

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        $method->setCarrier('proporta_customrate');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $method->setMethod('proporta_customrate');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
        $method->setPrice(0);
        $method->setCost(2);

        $result->append($method);

        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array('proporta_customrate' => $this->getConfigData('name'));
    }
}
```